# Workflow C# string function error in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I have an code issue in docusign.

In my calculation step I have created and input and output code.

When I run the template and checking the "incoming data" xml in the workflow I have an error message displayed:

> <In_80_stackTrace>Exception: at ADEXS.DynamicCode.DynamicClassD_3447d8ccd49f4631b91c31df53e249e7.DynamicMethodD_dcb572b7876d400683579290c5918f06(DynamicContext _context)</In_80_stackTrace>

I don't know how to fix this that it will show only the

```
logError("In_80_error", "Data node //CategoryName is missing");
```

when no data is in the node.

Below are the details - my input code:

```
//In_80 - ESP_CategoryName_Description
string In_80 = "";
{
    try
    {
        if (incomingDataRoot.SelectSingleNode("//CategoryName[node()]").InnerText == null)
        {
            logError("In_80_error", "Data node //CategoryName is missing");
        }
        else if (incomingDataRoot.SelectSingleNode("//CategoryName[node()]").InnerText != null)
        {
            In_80 = incomingDataRoot.SelectSingleNode("//CategoryName[node()]").InnerText;
        }
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       //logError("In_80_error", "Exception: Message:" + e.Message +" Inner Exception: "+ e.InnerException +" StackTrace: "+ e.StackTrace +" Source: "+ e.Source +" Data: "+ e.Data);
      logError("In_80_stackTrace", "Exception: " + e.StackTrace);
   }
}
```

Here is the output code:

```
//OUT_92 - ESP_CategoryName_Description
var OUT_92 = In_80;
if (In_80 == "") 
{
  logError("OUT_92_error", "Error reading In_80");
} else {
    XmlElement elem = incomingDataRoot.OwnerDocument.CreateElement("OUT_92");
    string p_category = "";
    int i = 1;
        foreach (char item in In_80)
        {
            if (Char.IsLetter(item))
            {


                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                            p_category += item.ToString().ToUpper();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            p_category += item.ToString().ToLower();

                    }
                    
                    i++;

            }
            else
            {
                        if (item == ' ')
                        {
                            i = 1;
                        }
                        
                        p_category += item.ToString();
            }
        }
        

    OUT_92 = p_category;
    elem.InnerText = OUT_92.ToString();
    elem.SetAttribute("Name", "ESP_CategoryName_Description");
    incomingDataRoot.SelectSingleNode("/Root/Params/TemplateFieldData/Calculation_Results").AppendChild(elem);
 }
```

In incoming data OUT part I'm getting

```
<OUT_92_error>Error reading In_80</OUT_92_error>
```

where I assume that its because something is wrong with the input code part?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: can you explain the DocuSign scenario here? you are using Connect webhook? what is this code trying to do?

Comment: Hi the code is in one of the calculations fields. Its purpose is to get a specific field value and change the text in to propper format --> TEST to Test etc... The issue is that when I look at the log Im getting an input error. I asume the string variable is wrong declared I dont know maybe the string value need to be a list? Previous programmers have created in workflow the calculation field where all c# calculations are running. I try to add some new one which I need. Simple math calculations are wokring but only convertion of text values is making some trouble.

Comment: I still don't understand how this code get the information. Is it using the REST API?